# DataNucleus Enhancer fails on LongIdentity. (datanucleus-maven-plugin 5.0.2)

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I was trying to create composite PK as follows for many-to-many-attributed relationship as documented [here](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jdo/guides/many_to_many_attributed.html): but could not enhance when I use `LongIdentity`. Is the current `DataNucleus Enhancer` not compatible with it?

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, cacheable = "false", detachable = "true",
    objectIdClass = CompanyProduct.PK.class)
public class CompanyProduct implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7578808257727591074L;

@PrimaryKey
private Company company; // PK
@PrimaryKey
private Product product; // PK
...

public static class PK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2090216333556951760L;
    public LongIdentity company; // Use same name as CompanyProduct field
    public LongIdentity product; // Use same name as CompanyProduct field

    public PK() {
    }

    public PK(String s) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "::");
        this.company = new LongIdentity(Company.class, st.nextToken());//
        this.product = new LongIdentity(Product.class, st.nextToken());//
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (company.toString() + "::" + product.toString());
    } 
...
```

Product.java

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, cacheable = "false", detachable = "true")
public class Product implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8269335445554701873L;


@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
long id;
@Persistent(mappedBy = "product")
private Set<CompanyProduct> companyProducts = new HashSet<>();
  ...
```

Company.java

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, cacheable = "false", detachable = "true")
public class Company implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6364869685797117033L;
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
//private 
long id;
@Persistent(mappedBy = "company")
private Set<CompanyProduct> companyProducts = new HashSet<>();
```

What am I doing wrong? `datanucleus-maven-plugin` version is 5.0.2 and `datanucleus-core` version is 5.1.6.

Comment: irrespective of your problem, why would you quote documentation for an old unsupported version? (which you don't seem to be using anyway)

Comment: @Billy Thanks for pointing it out. Where is the current documentation and version?

Comment: Well when I want their docs, I go to their home page and navigate to the version I am using; not sure why that is difficult to find. http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jdo/mapping.html

Comment: I have seen the doc. For lazy people like me, must I create PK for each class as in the doc? Is there any way to use the  "SingleFieldIdentity" builtin PK? Because if I use `public Company.PK company;` it means I have to create PK class for it and not the builtin PK class.

Comment: "SingleFieldIdentity" are not used by DataNucleus as such, and besides by doing that you tie your code to some internal JDO class. A "builtin" class is all well and good as long as you never need to refer to it, and by hardcoding it in your class you are referring to it. Clearly you could contribute handling that doesn't need that

Comment: Besides all of that, "best practice" would be to always use a separate PK field for the intermediate object (e.g surrogate (datastore) identity), rather than a composite PK, since that saves a lot of pain, and potentially is more efficient in database calls

Comment: It is always good to go for the "best practice". I would like to have an example of what you mean by "surrogate (datastore) identity"? I would like you to point me to a good example. Is it like the one you placed [here](https://github.com/datanucleus/samples-jdo/blob/master/many_to_many_attributed/src/main/java/org/datanucleus/samples/jdo/many_many_attributed/BusinessRelation.java)?

Comment: Either add a single field to the intermediate class to be its "application identity" (generated value), or specify it to use "datastore identity". Basic JDO

Comment: I am using the  "application identity" (generated value) for my classes. As you said the best practice is to create its internal subclass `static class PK` so that I can refer to its ID through  `public Company.PK company;` Right?

Comment: "Company.PK" has absolutely no place if you do what I said about "best practice"!!!

Comment: I did not understand exactly what you mean by `always use a separate PK field for the intermediate object`. May be an example can explain better. Thanks.

Comment: what I understood from that line is that I should switch to `datastore identity`. I am still searching to know what is `surrogate (datastore) identity` and how to use it in the relationship. I will appreciate it if I have a link to an example.

Comment: I have searched the net , I have not been able to see any example of relationship (1-1, 1-N, or N-M) using  surrogate (datastore) identity. If I  could see one it will make my work easy. For information, I use Neo4j Database and JDO.

Comment: Huh? http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jdo/mapping.html#datastore_identity  what datastore you're using has NOTHING to do with anything

Comment: if I am using `surrogate (datastore) identity` on this case, there will be no `Id` fields on Company and Product Classes. How about the PK fields on the relationship class `CompanyProduct`? How do we map the `companyProducts` to the `CompanyProduct`?

Comment: @DN1 Looking at  https://github.com/datanucleus/samples-jdo/tree/master/one_to_many_join_bidir it means one can use `surrogate (datastore) identity` for both `Company and Product` classes while `Application Identity` for the relationship class. Right?

Comment: I am thinking of creating a single field to the intermediate class to be its "application identity" (generated value) instead of `surrogate (datastore) identity`. Apart from the pains of writing the PK classes is there any other problem on using the Application Identity? If there is no other problems won't it be good to create the PK classes as the Q classes are created using `org.datanucleus.jdo.query` plugin?

Comment: @DN1 I have seen your new sample using `surrogate (datastore) identity` here https://github.com/datanucleus/samples-jdo/blob/master/many_to_many_attributed/src/main/java/org/datanucleus/samples/jdo/many_many_attributed2/Main.java . It seems that I am used to Application identity because `pm.getObjectId` gives me a figure unlike `datastore identity` which gives both figure and class name. I am thinking of creating a single field to the intermediate class to be its "application identity" as you suggested. With that I don't need to create PK manually. How about that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion and my trial on this case of deciding on which identity to use, I found it convenient to continue with the `Application identity` by adding a single field to the intermediate class to be its `Application identity` (generated value). With these I don't need to write the PK Class manually. Hence, I have my code as follows;

CompanyProduct.java  (many_to_many_attributed)

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, cacheable = "false", detachable = "true")
public class CompanyProduct implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7578808257727591074L;

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
long id;
@Persistent
private Company company;
@Persistent
private Product product; 

...
```

Company.java

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, cacheable = "false", detachable = "true")
public class Company implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6364869685797117033L;

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
long id;
@Persistent(mappedBy = "company")
private Set<CompanyProduct> companyProducts = new HashSet<>();

...
```

Product.java

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, cacheable = "false", detachable = "true")
public class Product implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8269335445554701873L;

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
long id;
@Persistent(mappedBy = "product")
private Set<CompanyProduct> companyProducts = new HashSet<>();
...
```

This is what I have settled for now unless one advised me against the use of "Application identity".  Thanks to @Billy and @DN1